# Automator "Output replaces selected text" not working

Tags: macos, automator

I am trying to write an Automator script, that replaces a given text by some other text. I followed the steps in

[Editing text in Automator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495102/editing-text-in-automator)

which are the same as given by a bunch of blog posts covering this topic and may vary with regards to the language the script is written in. I tried with AppleScript and with bash.

My (reduced example) bash script is:

```
echo hello
```

I have selected the option "Output replaces selected text".
I tried the script when selecting text in Xcode, TextEdit and another app. The text is not replaced (it remains the same). The script is executed - as I tested via `say hello` inside of the script. Also I followed the setup of:

http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/services.html

to make sure my script is enabled in "System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> [√] myService", because this tool used to work on my machine and it should have the same requirements for replacing text inside a TextView like the script I am going to write. Also I read the answer:

[Automator not working inside xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711871/automator-not-working-inside-xcode)

from which I could not deduct, what "give xcode access to be able to modify accessibility settings" means. I am running macOS 10.13.4.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured something out. After creating a copy of the script in the file system, the copy worked. The only difference was the name. Indeed, if I renamed the original script, it worked. The name was "resolveConflicts". I have no app in my PATH with the same name. The only place I used the same name was inside SourceTree -> Preferences -> Custom Actions. Renaming the action in SourceTree did not allow me to successfully run the script with the name "resolveConflicts". In the end I could not figure out, with which name the scripts collided. I also checked /System/Library/Services and /System/Services. No scripts with same name existed there. I sticked with a different name.